# botón dropdown detecte el final de un div

Tags: php, bootstrap

Tengo uno botón dropdown en una tabla, pero al cambiar de tamaño, el dropdown se pierde con el final, es decir, no muestra todas las opciones.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

la última celda, hace que la otras opciones no se miren, 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como puedo hacer que detecte el final y en lugar que despliegue hacia abajo lo haga hacia arriba o a un lado, o que se salgan del div para verlas?.

Actualización:

```
$opciones0  = "<div>";
    $opciones1  = "<div class='btn btn-group'>";
    $opciones2  = "<button class='btn dropdown-toggle' data-toggle='dropdown' style='width: 60px; background-color: transparent; border-color: #3BAFDA;'>";
    $opciones3  = "<span class='caret' style='border-width: 12px 10px 12px 10px; color: #3BAFDA !important;'></span>";
    $opciones4  = "</button>";
    $opciones5  = "<ul class='dropdown-menu' role='menu' style='background-color: #222; color:#fff; margin-left: -100px; '>";
    $opciones6  = "<li><a href='?mod=registroproductos&consultar&codigo=".$row['id']."' style='color:#fff;' class='btn btn-block mi_boton'><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-book'></i>&nbsp;Consultar</a></li>";
    $opciones7  = "<li><a href='?mod=registroproductos&editar&codigo=".$row['id']."' style='color:#fff;' class='btn btn-block mi_boton'><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-pencil'></i>Editar</a></li>";
    $opciones8  = "<li><a href='informe3.php?codigo=".$row['id']."' style='color:#fff;' class='btn btn-block mi_boton'><i class='fa fa-file-pdf-o'></i>Imprimir PDF</a></li>";
    $opciones9  = "<li><a style='color:#fff;' class='btn btn-block mi_boton' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#modal_debaja".$row['id']." '><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-off'></i>Dar de baja</a></li>";
    $opciones10 = "</ul>";
    $opciones11 = "</div>";
    $opciones12 = "</div>";

    $opciones = $opciones0.$opciones1.$opciones2.$opciones3.$opciones4.$opciones5.$opciones6.$opciones7.$opciones8.$opciones9.$opciones10.$opciones11.$opciones12;
```

Tabla:

```
<div class="box-body table-responsive">
          <script>
              $(document).ready(function(){
                  var dataTable=$('#ajax_table').DataTable({
                      language: {
                          "decimal": "",
                          "emptyTable": "No hay registros",
                          "info": "Mostrando _START_ a _END_ de _TOTAL_ Registros",
                          "infoEmpty": "Mostrando 0 to 0 of 0 Registros",
                          "infoFiltered": "(Filtrado de _MAX_ total de registros)",
                          "infoPostFix": "",
                          "thousands": ",",
                          "lengthMenu": "Mostrar _MENU_ Registros",
                          "loadingRecords": "Cargando...",
                          "processing": "Procesando...",
                          "search": "Buscar:",
                          "zeroRecords": "Registros no encontrados",
                          "paginate": {
                              "first": "Primero",
                              "last": "Ultimo",
                              "next": "Siguiente",
                              "previous": "Anterior"
                          }
                      },
                      "processing": true,
                      //"serverSide":true,
                      "ajax":{
                          url:"pages/fetch.php",
                          type:"post"
                      },
                      "columns": [
                          { "data": "id" },
                          { "data": "nserie" },
                          { "data": "tipo_arma" },
                          { "data": "departamento" },
                          { "data": "municipio" },
                          { "data": "empresa_cliente" },
                          { "data": "sede" },
                          { "data": "estado_semaforo" },
                          { "data": "opciones" }
              ]
                  });
              });
          </script>
          <table id="ajax_table" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
              <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th>NºSERIE</th>
                    <th>TIPO</th>
                    <th>DEPARTAMENTO</th>
                    <th>MUNICIPIO</th>
                    <th>EMPRESA</th>
                    <th>SEDE</th>
                    <th>ESTADO</th>
                    <th>OPCIONES</th>
                  </tr>
              </thead>
          </table>
        </div>
```

Comment: Por favor, agrega el código que tienes para tratar de reproducir el error.

Comment: Ya agregué la actualización de la pregunta.